# I cannot send data to datetime when posting to api from c# form application

Tags: c#, winforms, api, asp.net-web-api

I post to api with the c# form application. Among the data I need to send is datetime. I am writing the code below but cannot send the datetime.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DateTime datetimeValues = DateTime.Now;

   var values = new Values()
   {
      name = "example_name",
      datetime = datetimeValues
   }
   
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:20295/");
   HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/test", values).Result;
}
```

When I write this code, other data is sent without any problem, but datetime is sent as null. What could be the problem?

api/test post request;

```
 public string Post(Data data)
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = @"insert into Table 
                            (name, addedDate)
                            values(
                            '"+data.name+"', '"+data.addedDate+"')";
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["App"].ConnectionString))
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                da.Fill(dt);
            }

            return "Successful";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error!" + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, attach the code that handles POST request on `api/test`. It will be hard to help you without this information

Comment: I added api / test post request @AndreiKhotko

Comment: You have a lot of small problems in your code. Could you also add the definition of `Data` class and tell what database do you use while I'm writting the answer to your question?

Comment: I am using ms sql server. There are data I want to send in the data class. I have no problem sending this data. But when I want to send datetime via winform, it adds it as null. @AndreiKhotko

Comment: I would advice using, if possible, the same types client and server side (or making both adhere to the same interface) to avoid problems like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I write this code, other data is sent without any problem, but
> datetime is sent as null

That's because your `Data` class on server has property called `DateTime addedDate` whereas the client sends the contract `Values` with field `DateTime datetime`. The server accepts `DateTime` field with name `addedDate`.

So you have several options to fix it:

- Rename the property on client from `Values.datetime` to
  `Values.addedDate`
- Rename the property on server from `Data.addedDate` to
  `Data.datetime`
- Depending on the JSON-serialization library that is used by the
  server, use JSON PropertyName attribute. For instance, for the
  library JSON.NET (Newton JSON) it will be `[JsonProperty("name")]`.
  See the documentation here
  ([link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm))

P.S. The advice that is not related to the main question: Don't add the values of the parameters to the SQL query directly in the query string like you do. It's a huge hole in the security of your database. It's well-know problem called [SQL-Injection technique](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). To avoid it use `command.Parameters.Add()` method. In your case it would be something like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string query = "insert into Table (name, addedDate) values(@name, addedDate)";
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["App"].ConnectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = data.name;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@addedDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2);
    cmd.Parameters["@addedDate"].Value = data.addedDate;
    da.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: After what you wrote for the solution, I reviewed my code again and realized that I was missing a small detail. I will also consider your suggestions. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: You can add Parameter and Value in a single line, e.g.,: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = data.name;`. This is the usual form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the datetime as string on api/test, and on backend use `DateTime.TryParse();` to convert the date on format `DateTime`